# How do I do an internet speedtest from CLI on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I am have a couple pi's running headless raspbian that I SSH into, I wanted to know if there is any speedtest utility that I can use.

I am aware that I can download a file and check the speed that way but I wanted comprehensive download/upload data kind of what speedtest.net provides but CLI version of it.

Is that possible?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a package on github that does a speedtest.net sampling from the commandline, it is located here: https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli. Note that the author points out several potential pitfalls:

> There is the potential for this tool to report results inconsistent
>   with Speedtest.net. There are several concepts to be aware of that
>   factor into the potential inconsistency:
>
> 1. Speedtest.net has migrated to using pure socket tests instead of HTTP based tests
>
>    2. This application is written in Python. Different versions of Python will execute certain parts of the code faster than others
>    3. CPU and Memory capacity and speed will play a large part in
>         inconsistency between Speedtest.net and even other machines on the
>         same network

Comment: Can you please explain how to use it. Like a sudo apt-get command, and how to execute it aswell? I apologize I am still a noob when it comes to linux been using it for 6 months on and off but decided to migrate everything to it because I love the learning experience.

Comment: Have you read the instructions on the page I linked to? (https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) They provide 3 different ways to install (using `pip` directly, using `pip` with the github repo, or installing it by pulling using `wget`. Then you just run `speedtest-cli` to execute the test (or look at the options using `speedtest-cli -h`). Just make sure you have Python installed (Should be installed by default on the Pi if you use Raspbian)

Answer (score 5):

I used the following commands to install and execute the speedtest:

1.sudo apt-get install python-pip

2.sudo easy_install speedtest-cli

3. to execute "speedtest-cli"

works like a charm thanks Phil

Comment: because i installed it on 3 different systems two raspbians and one ubuntu I noticed that the easy install didnt work without the first command posted above. dont know why. using the pip method gave me errors.

Comment: I also got it to work on a Mac. Installation was different as it required homebrew to be installed on osx first, but awesome little program. Big Thumbs up to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of interest:
[Raspberry Pi Speedtester](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OgA1rYQU3UI8G4Krn-GiU1AyfHzQO3MwXlFPQ_vntsU/edit?usp=drivesdk)